# mean and variance

Tags: probability, variance, mean

Let X be a discrete random variable such that X = 0 with probability 0.5 and X = 1 with probability 0.5. Let Y be a discrete random variable such that Y = 1 when X = 1 and Y = 0 when X = 0. What is the mean and variance of X - 3Y (let W = X – 3Y)?

Calculated below
X and Y Mean 0.5
X and Y variance 0.25
Mean X-3Y - >>  0.5-3*.5 = -1.5
variance  X-3Y - >> .25-3 * .25 = -0.5

so answer is  -1.5 ns -0.5

but given options are -1, 1
-1, 0.5
1, -1
0.5, 1

where am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to CV! This looks like a textbook or homework question, in which case you should include the `self-study` tag (and make sure to read its explanation). To get you on your way: variances are never negative (*co*variance can be however), and if Y takes fixed values based on X, what is the variance that it adds?

Comment: you can rewrite this random variable $W$ as $W = -2X$ . Since the variance it's never negative as @PBulls pointed out you can see what happens

Comment: Two good comments already, and please do add that tag.  But also, check that you have copied the problem correctly.  Here X and Y are identical, which certainly could be how the problem was written, but seems odd.